# Crashlytics for ndk can't access system unwind

Tags: android-ndk, native, crashlytics, google-fabric

Crashlytics for ndk can't access system unwind with error info: *Failed to find any usable unwinding libraries on the device, falling back to simple unwinding*

Maybe this failure caused that we only got one line for the native crash.

My device is Nexus 6 with platform 7.1.1

Answer (score 2):

Mike from Fabric here. Yes, if we're unable to find libcorkscrew and libunwind then we switch to our own simple unwinder. The simple unwinder is only able to get the top-most frame in a crash which is why you're seeing this behavior. We plan on making this better.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. My further question is: Is there any solution for this? Could we add libunwind to our project to resolve this issue?

Comment: Not at the moment unfortunately, but as I mentioned we're working on making this better.

Comment: @MikeBonnell - any ETA on "making this better"?. One month later and still "Failed to find any usable unwinding libraries on the device, falling back to simple unwinding" on Android 5.0 and Android 7.0

Comment: I don't have an ETA I can share publicly. If you're interested in testing anything we may be working on, then email support(at)fabric(dot)io with a reference to this thread.